# Facebook Debugger caching improper DNS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns, facebook-opengraph

Yesterday our domain had an A record removed erroneously while the server was under high load, and Facebook debugger tool probably scraped the site many times while it was down.

The server is back to normal, and now whenever I use the debugger tool on the www version of our domain, I constantly get 502 bad response code, even though the site is working.

The TTL of DNS is 300 seconds (CloudFlare), but this caching problem is still happening a good 18 hours after the incident.

I temporarily resolved the issue by 302 redirecting to the non-www version of our domain and all our posts scrape perfectly now, although this is not ideal because I need www.

I set up a sample subdomain called 'test' and loaded the exact same content, and it works perfectly, so that eliminates malformed html as a problem (also the fact that non-www works fine with the exact same content).

As a further investigation, I removed the A record for the test subdomain and put it back a few minutes later, in order to emulate the initial incident. After waiting a solid hour (and with a TTL of 300), the Facebook debugger still returns 502 about 29 out of 30 times, and rarely I will get a 200.

Despite my test subdomain returning 200 very rarely, my www domain never returns 200 even after trying probably 1000 times, and the DNS was put back almost 24 hours ago.

Perhaps facebook cache expiration time is based on the number of requests it gets? During my test I only tried a few times, but during the time my site went down there were probably 10,000 shares or more taking place.

So overall it seems it's possible to "break" a subdomain from ever being scraped by adding and removing a dns record, even though the domain resolves just fine, long after the domain has propagated.

I really would like to use my www subdomain but it's just not happening until I can find a way for facebook to crawl it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it would appear this resolved itself after ~24 hours... I find it interesting how on my test domain it resolved within ~1 hour, while my www domain took 24 hours. That's what led me to believe there was 'something else', but it turns out there wasnt.

I presume there are different levels of how long something is cached for... and because my site was requested so many times it probably cached it for longer.

If this is happening to you, just wait it out.